# Facebook App not appearing in search results

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-social-plugins

I've created a new facebook application at developer.facebook.com with following details:

Canvas Page:
http://apps.facebook.com/utvtribe

However, this app is not appearing in search results, if i am trying to search in under search textbox at facebook, what can be the reason?

Please guide me,

Thanks,
Kul.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be automatically indexed into search after a few weeks and after reaching 10 MAU:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#search

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but my app has been out since 1/1/12 and has 3800 MAU, but it still isn't showing up in the search.  Do you have any other ideas about what may be wrong?